# Fixing normals without getting in edit mode

Tags: normals, polycount

I'm modeling a complex object,i did the high and low poly versions of this object and now i'm going to bake the normal maps ,but i've got a problem. I Split this object in a couple pieces,then i joined them together. I did for the lowpoly version, some normals got inverted, so i went to **Edit mode>Control+N** and it got fixed. The high poly version got those inverted normals aswell when i joined the pieces, however when i try to **Edit mode>Control+N** it crashes the whole PC because it has to many quads. I have a quite good PC for modelling (Core I5 3470/ GTX 760 / 12GB RAM)

I was wondering if there any way to fix the normals without getting into edit mode. Can you guys please help me? Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think edit mode is what's crashing your PC.  It's because you're trying to perform an operation on probably millions of tris.  If you *can* enter Edit mode, You could resplit the object by selection using *P* and then fix the normals of each part.  In the future, though, I would suggest using the Subdivision Surface modifier and NOT applying it.  That way it gets applied dynamically only when you go to render.

Comment: It makes sense, but i'm going to bake the normals and stuff. Aren't they supposed to be applied first and join the objects together?

Comment: So you're saying that even though the normals are correct in the individual parts, when you join them they face the wrong way?  I would try LukeD's answer and see if that addon does anything different than doing it in edit mode.  Please write back and confirm it worked.

Comment: Yes, the normals are right individually, but when i'm going to join them, some objects got their normals flipped, i don't know why this happen,but isn't the first time. I Tried LukeD's suggestion and it worked REALLY good and fast. But thank you for trying to help me, it was helpful.

Comment: Very glad you got it working, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I think that @bertmoog could be right I will try to answer your question and propose Add-on called [Flippist from Alexey Khlystov](http://alexiy.nl/flippist/).

[image: Flippist]

1. Download Add-on from link above and install/enable it as usual.
2. Select one (or multiple) object.
3. Hit <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, then type **Flippist**.
4. You can change settings by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> or in **Tool Shelf**.

Comment: I Liked this addon and it quickly fixed the normals. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @Imkls great to know, I've used this Add-on once or twice but for other purposes (multiple small objects). Kudos to Alexey Khlystov for such a great thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do the same action you're doing right now, but from the console. And be sure to switch back to object mode at the end. Maybe then it wont crash, because blender doesn't need to draw all those faces.

Comment: It's a cool tip friend, i'll use it.